# Is it possible to target Office Add-Ins in the Ribbon based on AD Properties?

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-office, add-in, ribbon

I am trying to build a new add-in command (button) to add to the Home tab in the Outlook ribbon. This is easy enough to do, but my organization also wants to target the button based on properties in one's Active Directory profile (specifically department). Is this possible? Thank you so much!

Comment: The following link for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward with desktop office add-ins (like VSTO). All you need to do is basically to get information about the currently logged in user organizational unit from the active directory, and then show/hide/modify buttons depending on this information.

From the tags on your question, it looks like this is NOT what you are looking for (please correct me if I am wrong)? The fact that you added "office365", probably means that you are interested in javascript (cloud/browser/store) solution?

For javascript-based add-ins, the part where you get the user department from its profile was impossible until recently. Now you may check out the [Single-Sign-On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) API (added last year). It provides you information from user's Azure active directory profile, meaning that your organization is supposed to be part of it.
Another difficulty could be, dynamic display of the related buttons (showing/hiding/enabling/disabling)  (I may be wrong, but it looks like it is still not supported for javascript). You can try to create a workaround for that by building a custom task pane instead (you can do whatever you want on your task pane)

--- update ---

In case of .NET VSTO add-in, you can get user groups using:

`UserPrincipal.Current.GetAuthorizationGroups()`

Then you can control which buttons/controls to show/hide by providing callback function(s) in your code and in your ribbon interface definition file (you need to define Ribbon using XML, not with UI designer). There are callbacks available like `getVisible`, `getLabel`, etc.

Comment: We are in a hybrid environment, but most people are still on-prem and mainly use the desktop client - I am totally okay with this button only appearing in the desktop client. I'm glad to hear it's possible - thanks so much!

I will look more into VSTO (to be quite honest I'm very new to the Microsoft stack with the exception of SharePoint) and how exactly I can dynamically show/hide the button based on AD properties. Thanks again!

Comment: Correct, there is no way to dynamically modify Ribbons in web add-ins; they are static and confined to their declarations in the add-in manifest

Comment: @JosefH: I have updated the answer.. There are a lot of information actually how to go about that with VSTO.